# ATA_PIIX Driver Source Code

Tags: linux, drivers, suse, sata

Is it possible to find the source code for the ATA_PIIX Driver outside the linux kernel? I have to install an older version of Linux (SuSE 10) on a brand new laptop and its failing to see the drive. I'd like to get a newer version of the driver to build for use in the automated build process.

Comment: It would probably be easier to backport an entire newer kernel to SuSE 10 than selectively backport drivers. Either way, you'll have the burden of maintaining security updates and bugfixes for a custom kernel.

Comment: @Faheem - Management does not want us to shoehorn a newer kernel to the older system; it was one of the first things I mentioned